# Ignore last data explode is taking? PHP

Tags: php, explode

let's say my code is.

```
<?php
$var = "1,2,3,4,5,6,";
$var_explode = explode(',', $var);
foreach ($var_explode as $number)
{
echo "$number test";
}
?>
```

And when it echos, it goes like, 1 test, 2 test, 3 test, 4 test, 5 test, 6 test, test. The last one is un-needed, I know its caused because I have a comma after the 6 in my variable, but I need that comma there, not going to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: I need it to ignore that comma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `trim($var, ',')` to remove the last comma when passing the string to the explode.

```
$var_explode = explode(',', trim($var, ','));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php

$var = "1,2,3,4,5,6,";
$var_explode = explode(',', $var);
array_pop($var_explode); // removes last  
foreach ($var_explode as $number)
{
echo "$number test";
}
?>
```